# Python requests getting same data no matter the ending of a url

Tags: python, dataframe, python-requests

I have some code that looks like this:

```
import pandas as pd
import requests
import csv

url = "https://rocketleague.tracker.network/rocket-league/distribution"

header = {
  "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/91.0.4472.106 Safari/537.36",
  "X-Requested-With": "XMLHttpRequest"
}


r = requests.get(url, headers=header)
df = pd.read_html(r.text)
df = pd.concat(df)
df = df.drop(df.index[22])
df = df.drop(columns=["Division II", "Division III"])
df.to_csv('start.csv')
```

Which takes the data on the site and places it into a CSV for me. However, there's a dropdown on the site that allows you to change playlists, and thankfully it points to another url:

https://rocketleague.tracker.network/rocket-league/distribution?playlist=11

As you can see, this takes you to '2v2' rather than '1v1' and offers a new set of data. However, even if I plug this url in, it still returns me the 1v1 data as though it were simply pointing to 'https://rocketleague.tracker.network/rocket-league/distribution'.

I'm really not sure where I'm going wrong here.

Answer (score 0):

In my personal experience, I have had similar problems. Because the content changes based on the click of the dropdown box, it means that the URL stays the same while content on the page may be different based on what drop-down box you've selected.

My solution would be to use Selenium as an alternative. This way you can select which page you'd like in the drop-down (1v1, 2v2, etc.) and then make requests to get the data.